# Если есть несколько кнопок с одинаковыми надписями и все вызывают одну и ту же команду, можно как-то их распознавать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, распознавание

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def show():
    if ("Pressed first button"):
        print("First")
    elif ("Pressed second button"):
        print("Second");
    else:
        print("Pressed third button")

for i in range(3):
    Button(root, text="Something", command=show())

root.mainloop()
```

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы команда распознавала , какая кнопка нажата. Я знаю как это через текст на кнопке сделать. Но вот если он одинаковый, не знаю как такое сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто нужно передавать номер кнопки как аргумент в функцию `show` вместо текста, смотрите тут примеры:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter

```
Button(root, text='Something', command = lambda: show(i))
```

Comment: Вроде бы в цикле нужно так: `Button(root, text='Something', command=lambda i=i: show(i))`, иначе в лямбду попадет одно и тоже значение -- последнее

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но сегодня я придумал гениальное (для меня) решение. Там ситуация просто другая, и цикл перебирает не значения из range, а список из кнопок с двумя вариациями текста. Но это уже совсем другая история...

Comment: @DreamRunner Ну так запостите ваше гениальное решение и примите свой ответ, пожалуйста